# Returning sum in one table in one row from a series of records per user_ID

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-design, asp.net-membership, saving-data

Assuming Main Table has 10 columns with an `Amount` column, which must be updated form a second table, the `DepositTable`, with `deposit` column

1. MainTable id is `titheID`, and is unique, hence no multiple identical values allowed.
2. `DepositTable` can have the same `titheID` on several rows following different dates of deposit.
3. I have tried

   ```
   SELECT titheID, SUM(deposit)
   FROM DepositTable
   GROUP BY titheID
   ```

   and it worked on the DepositTable but how to update the MainTable Amount column with the results for each titheID, is my puzzle.

Because of the Unique state of the titheID in the MainTable, It throws Constraints Exception.

Please help

Comment: do you want to only `update` the main table or `insert` missing `titheID` as well?

Comment: Why would you group on titheID considering it's unique?

Comment: what is the specific error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you'rre looking for somethinglike:

```
UPDATE MT
SET MT.Amount = Sec.Total
FROM MaiTable MT INNER JOIN (SELECT titheID, SUM(deposit) Total FROM DepositTable GROUP BY titheID) Sec ON MT.titheID = Sec.titheID
```

Am I right?

Comment: Thanks @Simone for reminding me what I have long forgotten. I saw the error in my variable     MT.Amount = sec.Total ; I modified this to  sec.Amount and it worked

Comment: I'm glad of having been of some help, and if it worked mark it as answered :)

Comment: I just posted another issue: reading data into a form from table columns, editing and updating as well based on user_ID